# Store Parent/Child in a Batch Put on Appengine with Objectify

Tags: java, google-app-engine, objectify

I'd like to store 2 new entities in a batch put. However, one entity is the parent of the other. If I have a a field in the child object that looks like:

@Parent
private Key parent

How do I fill in a value for this field in the child object if the parent hasn't been stored yet (and thus has no key yet).

Comment: Have you tried with transactinons?

Comment: The question remains how do I do it as one batch put as opposed to two calls to the datastore? Or are transactions all one call to data store?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Allocate the id of the parent in advance.  Then you can save the parent and the child (with a parent key reference) in a single batch put.

Answer (score 0):

Yo can not do it that way (as one batch).

If your question is more concerned with data integrity, then you may use transactions.
Example:

```
from google.appengine.ext import db
from app.models import ParentModel, ChildModel

class ARequestHandler(BaseHandler):
    def get(self):
        def create_parent_and_child():
            parent_entity = ParentModel(...)
            parent_entity.put()

            child_entity = ChildModel(Parent=parent_entity, ...)
            child_entity.put()


        db.run_in_transaction(create_parent_and_child)
```